# Mocking pthread_create using gmock

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a method that calls `pthread_create(...)`. is it possible to mock and expect the output of `pthread_create` so I don't actually launch a thread?

I am asking this because the entire class is a Mock Object and as soon as I delete the object at the end of the test case the thread segments.

Comment: Does the mock object's destructor do something related to the thread? It shouldn't just segfault because its constructing object is gone.

Comment: yes the destructor, deletes local information needed by the thread

Comment: That is likely causing the problem - the thread is trying to access data that you deleted. You should send the thread some sort of signal to exit, then wait for it to finish with `pthread_join` before deleting its data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Declare mock class and functions:

```
struct phtread_interface
{
    virtual int pthread_create(...) = 0;
    ... // other methods
};

class pthread_mock : public phtread_interface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(pthread_create, int(...));
    ....
};

pthread_interface *current_pthread_mock;

void set_current_pthread_mock(phtread_interface *mock)
{
    current_pthread_mock = mock;
}

int pthread_create(...)
{
    return current_pthread_mock->pthread_create(...);
}
```

In every test function do following:

```
pthread_mock mock_obj;
set_current_pthread_mock(&mock_obj);

// set expectations over mock_obj, use pthread_create ...
```

In source file with `pthread_create` add conditional include like:

```
#ifndef TESTING
#include <pthread.h>
#else
#include "pthread_mock.h"
#endif
```